# Number of relations that are both symmetric and antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Because one relation cannot be symmetric and antisymmetric in relation to another, but is always symmetric and reflexive to itself, there are 2^n relations (relations in the diagonal only). Is that right?

Comment: That's right. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Consider representing relations $R$ as $n \times n$ matrices (where $R$ is a relation on a set of cardinality $n$; call it $S = \{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$). Denote the elements $r_{i,j}$ for the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column element. Then $r_{i,j} = 1$ if $a_i R a_j$ and $0$ otherwise.

With this in mind, properties arise, such as:

- $R$ is symmetric if $R=R^T$.
- $R$ is antisymmetric if, for non-diagonal entries, one of $r_{i,j}=0$ or $r_{j,i}=0$ for particular but unequal $i,j$. That is, you cannot have $r_{i,j} = r_{j,i} = 1$.

With this, we notice that, in $R^T$, $r_{i,j}$ goes to the position of $r_{j,i}$. If $R=R^T$ as well, then $r_{i,j} = r_{j,i}$. However, antisymmetry requires at least one of these be zero, and thus if $R$ represents a symmetric and antisymmetric relation, $r_{i,j}=0$ for all $i \ne j$.

Then for all $n$ elements $r_{i,i}$ on the diagonal, we have two choices: either it is or is not related to itself (i.e. we can choose any diagonal entry freely to be $0$ or $1$). This gives $2^n$ possibilities.